# 16.04.3 LTS on reboot does not display wireless networks

Tags: networking

```
$cat /etc/pm/config.d/config
SUSPEND_MODULES="ath9k wlp2s0"
```

---

```
$cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet dhcp
```

With the above config, my wireless networks do not show up after a reboot. 
If I comment out the lines in */etc/network/interfaces*, my wireless networks show up after a reboot.

Do you know why ?

Comment: Maybe because it is misconfigured in `/etc/network/interfaces`, the part with `wpa-conf` is missing. If you comment the lines the NetworkManager takes care of the WiFi.

Comment: Like @Thomas wrote, your network is managed by Network Manager, check contents of `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`, there should be a file for your wifi connection

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to make my machine an access point, would I need to add an entry in /etc/network/interfaces  or /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections.